# u-boot can't save environment parameters when 'bootm 'specified

Tags: u-boot

I'm trying to modify the u-boot environment parameters with `setenv` command.

When I config `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; bootm` with `bootm` specified, uboot start loading the Linux kernel but I can't save parameters with `saveenv`.

When I config `bootcmd` without `bootm` I can save the parameters with saveenv but then uboot can't load the kernel, I got the following log

```
T T T T T T #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     #################################################################
     ##########
done
Bytes transferred = 2378156 (2449ac hex)
Unauthorized >
```

I can load the kernel directly by running `bootm`.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are calling this at the u-boot command line.

```
bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; bootm
```

The important note here is that the semicolon is a command separator. A simple fix (untested) would to add the command saveenv before the bootm command.

```
bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; saveenv; bootm
```

This would set the variable *bootcmd* to: tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2

Then *saveenv* would save the variable(s)

Then *bootm* would boot the image in memory.

You would **not** need to do this on every boot *if* you save the variables after you are content with the boot order.

**First set all u-boot variables for your setup.** (examples only. adjust for your setup)

- setenv autostart yes
- setenv bootfile uImage2
- setenv ipaddr 192.168.2.2
- setenv serverip 192.168.2.X
- setenv bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2

OR

- setenv bootcmd bootp 0x80800000 uImage2

**Save the u-boot variables to persistent media**

```
saveenv
```

**Test boot options by running the bootcmd**

```
run bootcmd
```

Repeat until the variables are set correctly and the bootcmd works.

> If U-Boot is not interrupted after the delay established in bootdelay, the automatic boot process
>   takes place. Automatic booting consists of running what is specified in the bootcmd environment
>   variable

**Some system variables:**

- *bootcmd*: Defines a command string that is automatically executed when the initial countdown is not interrupted. Executed only when the bootdelay variable is also defined.
- *autoload*: If set to "no" (or any string beginning with 'n'), the rarpboot, bootp, or dhcp command performs a configuration lookup from the BOOTP / DHCP server but does not try to load any image using TFTP.
- *autostart*: If set to "yes", an image loaded using the rarpboot, bootp, dhcp or tftpboot commands is automatically started (by internally calling the bootm command).
- bootfile: Name of the default image to load with TFTP.

Comment: in fact by setting `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; saveenv; bootm` it will save the command `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2` then boot and this is not what I wanted. I wanted to save the whole command `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; saveenv; bootm`

Answer (score 0):

I succedded to save the whole command `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; saveenv; bootm` by adding double quotes after `bootcmd`

```
setenv bootcmd "tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; bootm"
```

Comment: Why do you have to save the variable bootcmd every time with setenv? Does bootcmd settings not persist between boots?

Comment: no I didnt want to save it everytime, I just wanted to save once the whole command `bootcmd tftpboot 0x80800000 192.168.2.2:uImage2; bootm` but when I run `setenv bootcmd`  command without quotes, it boot the kernel and I no longer have access to uboot prompt to perform `saveenv`